# Panorama Control in Universal Windows App

Tags: xaml, silverlight, win-universal-app, panorama-control

I´m wondering if there´s a way to implement the Panorama Control from Windows phone 8 into Microsofts new universal Windows platform. The look and feel of the Panorama Control is great and I really can´t figure out why Microsoft didn´t implement this Control into UWP.

Actually I´m new to UWP (Coded WinForms Projects, only) and I´m looking for some layouting Standards which can help me to create applications for multiple devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UWP you can use [Hub](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/hub) or [Pivot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.pivot.aspx) controls

Take a look at [Navigation design basics for UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/navigation-basics)